# Get last N rows in each group where N value is dynamic based on joined table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

So there are 2 tables,

```
table_1 - id, limit_number
table_2 - id, created_at, table_1_id
```

Our requirement is to select last N rows in table_2 for each table_1_id group, where N is `limit_number`

Sample data

```
table_1

id, limit_number

1, 3
2, 1
```

```
table_2

id, created_at, table_1_id

1, ..., 1
2, ..., 1
3, ..., 1
4, ..., 1
5, ..., 2
6, ..., 2
```

The result should be

```
table_2

id, created_at, table_1_id
2, ..., 1
3, ..., 1
4, ..., 1
6, ..., 2
```

The values returned for each `table_1_id` are following `limit_number` here.

I tried using the `PARTITION()` function to assign ranks but it isn't working for dynamic value of N. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how you can do it :

```
select t2.*
from
(
    select *,row_number() over (partition by table_1_id order by created_date desc) rn from table2
)t2 
join table_1 t on t.limit_number >= t2.rn and t2.table_1_id = t.id
```

you can change `created_date desc` in order by to whatever make sense like `Id desc`